# Where did my code go wrong in using python while loop?

Tags: python

Question

> [image: This is my question]

And this is what I've tried

[image: And this is what I've tried]

I don't know what's wrong (they keep saying indentation is wrong and my code stops after user enter only one, I need it to consistently ask user input after the condition is True and executed)  I keep messing up my concept on while loops and for loops. Please help me, Thank you!

Comment: Please include your code and question as text

Comment: I'm really curious how the close-voters justify this "not being about programming". This is a very specific programming question, and the user has posted their code and what's going wrong.

Comment: @CollinD Yes, the close *reason* is wrong ... it should be closed but for "needs details or clarity" (because it has code as an image).

Answer (score 3):

You need to move `break` back an indentation:

```py
while cost_price <= 0:
    break
```

Note that this loop will never run, as it breaks as soon as it's triggered

As you asked for:

> I need it to consistently ask user input after the condition is True and executed

you may want to wrap the `input` in a `while` loop

```py
cost_price = -1

while cost_price <= 0:
    cost_price = int(input('Enter cost price > 0: '))
```

In a loop, this runs as:

```
Enter cost price > 0: -1
Enter cost price > 0: 0
Enter cost price > 0: 1
# The loop has broken, because cost_price > 0
# cost_price now = 1
```